# Word Tank-chain-wheel Challenge

Tags: word, english, open-ended

My niece gave me this [word wheels challenges](http://www.activityvillage.co.uk/word-wheel-challenge-1) the other day and I  comes up with an alternative.  Here's how this challenge works:

Find a word that can form another word by moving its first letter to the end of the word, or vice versa.

Example:

> EMIT
>   MITE
>   ITEM

Until you can no longer form another word.  Here's the rule:

- Must be a word found in dictionary, or a common name.
- Must be at least 3 letters long.
- Must have at least 1 rotation.
- Plural form (end with s) counts as 1 rotation only if you can form another word afterward.
- Please don't be like my niece and use the example as an answer...

Scoring:

- 1 point for each letter used ("emit" will has 4 points)
- 1.5 point for each 'rotation' it can have ("emit" has 2 rotations, thus 3 points)
- 1 point if the word can be loop infinitely.

Highest score wins.

<strike>This challenge will remains open for at least 2 days.</strike>

---

Time's up!

Highest score:
Dr Xorile - 11.5
Engineer Toast - 11.5

Base on the time the answer is submitted, Dr. Xorile will be the winner of this challenge! There are some creative answers which I like much! Thanks for everyone's participation.

Comment: So, the question is? :D

Comment: @GintasK there you got it :D

Comment: Technically "antidisestablishmentarianism" is worth 28 points. You might want to set a minimum number of rotations or lower/eliminate the weighting for length, or even without this loophole the question will become "what's the longest word you can put 's' in front of".

Comment: thanks all, I should add a rule to prevent these

Comment: Imho, a short word that loops infinitely should be worth more than a long word that loops once or twice.

Comment: @Carl not necessary, it's only 1 point for infinite loop

Comment: @Alex I mean that the rules should be such that "ate" is worth more than "denunciate". Maybe each iteration of an infinite loop is worth the amount of letters. Idk, just a thought.

Comment: @Carl "Maybe each iteration of an infinite loop is worth the amount of letters" - each iteration of an *infinite* loop? So a 3-letter word that loops infinitely would be worth 3x infinity?

Comment: @Adeptus I was wondering if I should reword that... "ate" is an infinite loop of three letters, so it's worth 3 times the amount of iterations, 3 squared.  Plus the 4.5 makes it 13.5.  Again, it's just an example of my hypothetical.

Comment: @Carl Yes Carl that would be more appropriate scoring as it was my intention to get more "looping" word then just a long word that loop once.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without better defining "word" or "common name" it turns into an ill-defined, open-ended puzzle (and [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the obvious "trick" for getting around the plural thing is to use a past-tense:

> denunciate -> enunciated gives 11.5

is the best I could find.  In a similar vein:

> devaluate -> evaluated gives 10.5

If you avoid this trick, then there are other options:

> trusties -> rustiest gives 9.5

Although this all works with the scoring system, I think the prettiest answer so far was given by @gannolloy

> stripe -> tripes -> ripest (9.0)

The only other one I can think of that's similar is:

> stable -> tables -> ablest (9.0)

I'm struggling to find anything that has more rotations apart from 3 letter words (ate->tea->eat; asp->spa->pas (which is a bit weak)). I can't find anything longer than the two above.

I quite like this one which is one letter shorter:

> route-> outer->utero (8.0 points)

because it doesn't use any "s" or "d" at all! Similar, but not as good (imho) are:

> amass->massa->assam (if that second word is not too politically incorrect), and saver->avers->versa

Comment: What are trusties?

Comment: [Apparently it's a word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trusties)

Comment: @Strawberry typically they're well behaved prisoners who are given benefits accordingly - they're "trusted" to not cause problems.

Comment: It's the name I give to my favourite underpants

Comment: I won't add sear to my answer in full, for reasons that will become clear to anyone willing to work through the two rotations...

Comment: levi->evil->vile is so close to getting all the way around...

Comment: I suppose invitee and e-invite is unacceptable?

Answer (score 9):

> STRIPE > TRIPES > RIPEST

6 + 3 = 9

Also, if names can be used:

> ESTON > STONE > TONES > ONEST

5 + 4.5 = 9.5 (Eston is a town in England)

Also, just for fun (Probably invalid):

> SHIRE > HIRES > IRESH (Name of Indian/Hindu Origin) > RESHI (A people from a book series The Stormlight Archive) > ESHIR (A type of werewolf creature from the game Summoners War) > SHIRE

5 + 7.5 + 1 = 13.5. Conclusion: if you google anything you will find a result

Comment: onest? I'll be 'onest - that's a pretty old word!

Comment: Your last one would actually be 5 + 4*1.5 + 1 = 12!

Comment: I am not a smart man.

Comment: @charfellow: not true: there are 5 rotations. The correct value is 13.5.

Comment: @gannolloy "TRIPES" and "TONES" disqualify your first two answers, since they are plural.

Comment: @IanMacDonald They work because they have another rotation after. That rule is just to prevent people from using a long word that starts with s and then moving it to the end and getting a ton of points. If you have another rotation after that its a valid set, at least by my understanding.

Comment: And @IanMacDonald wouldn't the rotation from ESHIR to SHIRE not be one because it starts at SHIRE?

Comment: @gannolloy: It's still a unique rotation that you haven't counted yet, even if it creates the initial word.

Answer (score 7):

> ATE -> TEA -> EAT -> ATE

So $3+4.5+1=8.5$

And a non-looping word:

> STRAPPING -> TRAPPINGS

10.5

Comment: Not sure if the rules are 100% clear - is the botton suggestion valid in regards to *"plural form (end with s) counts as 1 rotation only if you can form another word afterward."* ?

Comment: i always thought a 'trapping' looked a bit silly, so its singular, but check out ELU.

Comment: There are some words that don't have a singular form (or said form is never used.) 'Pants' is another good example. Trappings is definitely plural, and in fact has a singular form, according to m-w: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trapping

Answer (score 5):

> STOPPING -> TOPPINGS

8 + 1.5 = 9.5

Comment: I upvoted this answer as it appears before I added the 4th rule;  Please don't downvote it for violating the rules.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a higher score than the current highest but it is a lot more examples of that score.

All words are 11.5 points (10 letters, 1 rotation)

```
enucleated => denucleate   
enunciated => denunciate
```

Words that break the plural rule:

```
crumplings => scrumpling   
crunchings => scrunching   
educements => seducement     
lumberings => slumbering   
motherings => smothering   
omniphobes => somniphobe   
peculators => speculator   
tablemates => stablemate   
totterings => stottering   
tricklings => strickling   
wallowings => swallowing   
witherings => swithering   
wordmakers => swordmaker
```

Comment: Except that 13 of them break the plural rule!

Comment: @DrXorile That's what I get for not reading very carefully. Thanks.

Comment: You've also got a better word list than I do!

Comment: @DrXorile Litscape. I'd give a link but I'm on mobile. It's very useful for puzzles like this.

Comment: @DrXorile OK, here's the subpage I actually used from [Litscape](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools_mammoth_uncensored/pattern_match_words.php)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some fun ones

> emanate -> manatee

7 + 1.5 = 8.5 pts

> gelatin -> elating

7 + 1.5 = 8.5 pts

> height -> eighth

6 + 1.5 = 7.5 pts

> khan -> hank -> ankh

4 + 1.5 * 2 = 7 pts

**Clever 's' ones**

> slaughter -> laughters
>  swordplay -> wordplays
>  slowdown -> lowdowns

Answer (score 2):

STARE -> TARES -> AREST

$5+3=8$

Comment: Do you mean "arrest"?

Comment: I think "Arest" is a valid word: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Arest

Answer (score 2):

This uses an archaic word, so you might want to limit that use...

> STANG --> TANGS --> ANGST

For 5 + 3 = 8

Comment: "archaic"??? my 5L V8 begs to differ

Answer (score 1):

> EAR -> ARE

$3+ 1.5 => 4.5$

> RANGE -> ANGER

$5 + 1.5 => 6.5$

The plural items:

> SEAR -> EARS
>
>  SCOPE -> [COPES](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/copes)
>
>  SELECT -> ELECTS
>
>  SELECTION -> ELECTIONS